# How can I find $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}(1+\frac{x}n)^{\sqrt{n}}$?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, exponential-function

> How can I find $$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\left(1+\frac{x}n\right)^{\sqrt{n}}\;?$$

I know $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\left(1+\frac{x}n\right)^{n}  = \exp (x)$ but I don't know how can I put the definition in this particular limit.

I know then, that $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\big(1+\frac{x}n\big)=1$, but I don't think this is right to consider.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\left(1+\frac{x}n\right)^{\sqrt{n}}  = \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\left[\left(1+\frac{x}n\right)^{{\frac{n}{x}}}\right]^{{\frac{x}{n}}{\sqrt{n}}}$$ 
From 
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\left[\left(1+\frac{x}n\right)^{{\frac{n}{x}}}\right]=e \quad \text{and} \quad \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}{{\frac{x}{n}}{\sqrt{n}}}=0,$$ **, we get
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\left(1+\frac{x}n\right)^{\sqrt{n}}  = e^0=1$$

**EDIT**
*I add the note bellow as my calculation was considered insufficiently justified*

**and because the terms are positive, and we don't have an indeterminate case $0^0$ or $1^{\infty}$ or $\infty ^0,\;$

Comment: One needs an argument for "if $a_n\to a$ and $b_n\to b$ ($b_n,b\geqslant0, a_n,a>0$) then $a_n^{b_n}\to a^b$".

Comment: Or, if you prefer, put $t={n \over x}.$ The mentioned limit becomes $\lim_{t \to \infty} (1+{1\over t})^{t}.$

Comment: What do you use for the "we get..." step in the last line?

Comment: @user376343 I think what user587 is driving at is that you've assumed that you can distribute the limit $\lim_n a_n^{b_n} $ into $(\lim_n a_n)^{(\lim_n b_n)}$ but this isn't necessarily justified.

Comment: From 
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left[\left(1+\frac{x}n\right)^{{\frac{n}{x}}}\right]=e \quad \text{and} \quad \lim_{n\to\infty}{{\frac{x}{n}}{\sqrt{n}}}=0,$$ we get
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1+\frac{x}n\right)^{\sqrt{n}}  =\lim_{n\to\infty}\left[\left(1+\frac{x}n\right)^{{\frac{n}{x}}}\right]^{{\frac{x}{n}}{\sqrt{n}}}
\color{red}{
=\left[\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1+\frac{x}n\right)^{{\frac{n}{x}}}\right]^{\lim_{n\to\infty}{\frac{x}{n}}{\sqrt{n}}}
}
\color{blue}{= e^0}
$$ You have the blue one, but you need the red part, which is not explicitly justified.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**:

Compute the limit of the log: $\;\sqrt n\log\Bigl(1+ \dfrac xn\Bigr)$ and use *equivalence*:
$$\log(1+u)\sim_0 u.$$

Comment: I'd like to add an addendum to this answer since I wasn't sure about justifying the exchange of $\log(1+u)$ with $u$. Since $\log(1+u)\sim u$, $\lim_{u\to\infty}\frac{\log(1+u)}{u}=1$ so $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\log(1+x/n)/\left(\frac{x}{n}\right)}{\sqrt{n}/{\left(\frac{x}{n}\right)}}=\frac{\lim(\ldots)}{\lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt{n}{\left(\frac{n}{x}\right)}}$.

Answer (score 3):

Let $y=(1+\frac{x}{n})^{\sqrt{n}}$. Note that 
$$
\ln y=\sqrt{n}\ln(1+\frac{x}{n})=\frac{\ln(1+\frac{x}{n})}{1/\sqrt{n}}.
$$
As $n\to\infty$, this is a limit of the form $0/0$. Thus, we may apply L'Hopital's rule to obtain that
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\ln y=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{-\frac{x}{n^{2}}/(1+\frac{x}{n})}{-\frac{1}{2}n^{-3/2}}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{2x}{\sqrt{n}+\frac{x}{\sqrt{n}}}=0
$$
Thus, 
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}y=\lim_{n\to\infty}e^{\ln(y)}=e^{\left(\lim_{n\to\infty}\ln(y)\right)}=e^{0}=1.
$$

Answer (score 2):

Hint for $x\geq1$:

1. The expression and therefore the limit is relatively easily seen to be greater than or equal to $1$
2. The expression is for any $\epsilon>0$ eventually smaller than $\left(1+\frac xn\right)^{\epsilon n}$

Answer (score 1):

By L'Hopital, 
$$
\lim_{y\to\infty}\sqrt{y}\log(1+\frac{x}{y})
=\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{\log(1+tx)}{\sqrt{t}}
=\lim_{t\to 0}\dfrac{\frac{x}{1+tx}}{\frac{1}{2\sqrt{t}}}=0.
$$
Now one can use the continuity of the exponential function: 
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\exp\left[\sqrt{n}\log(1+\frac{x}{n})\right]
=\exp\left[\lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt{n}\log(1+\frac{x}{n})\right]=1.
$$